# Range of numbers in a column with Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, range, tablesorter

I came across one problem lately. I intended to use this type [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html) with slider filter and tried to modify it, but it didnt work.
I need to be able to work with range of numbers in the table columns (ie not just single numbers like 51, but 3-8).
So that when I pick value 5 on a slider filter, I need it to show the row with column value 3-8 and not column with value 51.

Please, do you have any ideas on how to modify this in order to use numeric range in the table?

Comment: Can you share some code? An HTML example of what your table looks like would really help. Use can use [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/900/) as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a combination of the `filter_formatter` and `filter_functions`, like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/901/)):

HTML

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
            <th>Range</th>
            <th>Animals</th>
            <th>Sites</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>abc 123</td><td>1-10</td><td>Koala</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 1</td><td>38-55</td><td>Ox</td><td>http://www.yahoo.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 9</td><td>4-10</td><td>Girafee</td><td>http://www.facebook.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>zyx 24</td><td>11-22</td><td>Bison</td><td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 11</td><td>13-43</td><td>Chimp</td><td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 2</td><td>28-60</td><td>Elephant</td><td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 9</td><td>9-25</td><td>Lion</td><td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ABC 10</td><td>9-23</td><td>Zebra</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>zyx 1</td><td>19-29</td><td>Koala</td><td>http://www.mit.edu/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>zyx 12</td><td>0-6</td><td>Llama</td><td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                1: function (e, n, f, i) {
                    var parts = e.split('-'),
                        val = parseFloat(f),
                        min = parseFloat(parts[0]),
                        max = parseFloat(parts[1] || 999); // default max = 999
                    return val >= min && val <= max;
                }
            },
            filter_formatter: {
                1: function ($cell, indx) {
                    return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiSlider($cell, indx, {
                        values: 0,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 60,
                        delayed: false,
                        exactMatch: false,
                        valueToHeader: false
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```