# jQuery tablesorter range sorting

Tags: php, jquery, range, tablesorter

I want to sort the price range properly. How can I do that?

```
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'pricerange',
    is: function(s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s,table,cell) {
        // format your data for normalization
        var cellTxt = s.replace("USD", "").replace(",","");
        console.log(cellTxt);
        return cellTxt;

    },
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'nemeric'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnd4t6uy/2/

Comment: I find the problem may be caused by two header row... However, i have to keep this layout. Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Would the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852837/range-of-numbers-in-a-column-with-tablesorter) solve your problem? Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/901/).

Comment: It seems cannot work...

Comment: I can get your solution correct when there is only 6 digit. If there is 7 digits, it will sort incorrectly

Comment: I get the solution. The problem is just because of two header row. I cannot extract the comma from the column properly.
solution is here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnd4t6uy/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question got me thinking about how to determine if the number entered as a search query would be within a listed range within the table. So, now I have [a demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom-search2.html) that shows you how to add a new filter search type.

This code only works with my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html)

```
$(function() {

  // Add insideRange filter type
  // ============================
  // This allows you to enter a number (e.g. 8) and show the
  // resulting rows that will have that query within it's range
  var ts = $.tablesorter,
    isDigit = /\d+/,
    nondigit = /[^\d,.\-()]/g,
    range = /\s+-\s+/;

  ts.filter.types.insideRange = function( c, data ) {
    if ( isDigit.test( data.iFilter ) && range.test( data.iExact ) ) {
      var t, val, low, high,
        parts = data.iExact.replace( nondigit, '' ).split( '-' );
      // the cell does not contain a range
      if ( isNaN( parts[0] ) || isNaN( parts[1] ) ) {
        return null;
      }
      low = ts.formatFloat( parts[0], c.table );
      high = ts.formatFloat( parts[1], c.table );
      val = ts.formatFloat( data.iFilter.replace( nondigit, '' ), c.table );
      if ( high < low ) {
        // swap high & low
        t = high; high = low; low = t;
      }
      return low <= val && val <= high;
    }
    return null;
  };

  // call the tablesorter plugin
  $("#table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widthFixed : true,
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
      // set to false because it is difficult to determine if a filtered
      // row is already showing when looking at ranges
      filter_searchFiltered : false
    }
  });

});
```

And [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1/) if you want to mess around with the code.