# Range of numbers in a column with Tablesorter in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, range, tablesorter

I intended to use [Tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html) plugin to sort table in my wordpress theme. At one of my table column I have a range of values (i.e. 8-10, 5-12 and so on). On this column the sorting doesnt work. I saw the solution [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852837/range-of-numbers-in-a-column-with-tablesorter) in stackoverflow. I tried to implement this but with no luck. In general sorting works on my table, however it gives incorrect results on that column.

Here is my header file where I include scripts:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
```

Here is my table

```
 <table cellspacing='0' id="posts-table"> <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->

            <!-- Table Header -->
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
                <th>Col4</th>
                <th>Col5</th>
                <th>Col6</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Table Header -->

            <!-- Table Body -->

            <?php /* Start the Loop */
            $i = 1;?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                $val1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'x-value', true);
                $post_categories = get_the_category();
                $categories_by_id = array();
                foreach ( $post_categories as $category ) {
                    $categories_by_id[$category->cat_ID] = $category;
                }
                foreach ( $post_categories as $category ) {
                    unset( $categories_by_id[$category->category_parent] );
                }

                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="align-center">'; echo $i++; echo'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'; echo end($categories_by_id)->cat_name; echo'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'; echo the_title(); echo'</td>';
                        echo '<td class="align-center">'; echo $val1; echo'</td>';
                        echo '<td class="align-center">'; echo $val1; echo'</td>';
                        echo '<td class="align-center">'; echo $val1; echo'</td>';
                    echo'</tr>';

                ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- Table Body -->
        </table>
```

And this is initialization of tablesorter

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#posts-table").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        sortList: [[1,0]],
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                1 : function(e, n, f, i) {
                    var parts = e.split('-'),
                        val = parseFloat(f),
                        min = parseFloat(parts[0]),
                        max = parseFloat(parts[1] || 999); // default max = 999
                    return val >= min && val <= max;
                }
            },
            filter_formatter     : {
                1 : function($cell, indx){
                    return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiSlider( $cell, indx, {
                        values : 0,
                        min : 0,
                        max : 60,
                        delayed : false,
                        exactMatch: false,
                        valueToHeader : false
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

);

Any thoughts why this isnt working? Sorry if it sounds stupid. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The `filter_formatter` code is used with a separate filter formatter file. I don't think it's necessary, or it might be the cause of the code not working for you.

Remove that block of code and see if it fixes your sorting issues ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/5413/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        sortList: [[1, 0]],
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                1: function (e, n, f, i) {
                    var parts = e.split('-'),
                        val = parseFloat(f),
                        min = parseFloat(parts[0]),
                        max = parseFloat(parts[1] || 999); // default max = 999
                    return val >= min && val <= max;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where should I put this function? Since I'm using wordpress, my $(document).ready(function() goes into the jquery.tablesorter.js file. Should I put this function in that particular file? I also noticed that you include the file jquery.tablesorter.widgets-filter-formatter.js in your jsfiddle demo, however the link to the file seems to be broken. Is that file important?